# Программа не работает так, как надо

Tags: python

Задача звучит так:
Напишите программу, в которой пользователь вводит имя
текстового файла, а программа отображает содержимое этого
файла, а также создает копию этого файла с пронумерованными
строками.

Моя программа копирует, но не нумерует, хотя на мой взгляд - должна.
Помогите пожалуйста. Что не так?

```
import shutil
x = str(input('Введите имя файла: '))
y = open(f'D:\\Txtfiles\\{x}')
z = y.read()
print(z)
shutil.copyfile(f'D:\\Txtfiles\\{x}', f'D:\\Txtfiles\\3.txt')
v = open('3.txt', 'w+t')
n = 0
for i in v:
    n += 1
    v.writelines(str(n) + ')' + i)
y.close()
v.close()
```

Comment: Посмотри, что делает режим w+. А потом посмотри, что ты делаешь с этим открытым файлом.

Answer (score 0):

Та же самая реализация задачи, без лишнего кода, не нужно копировать файл чтобы потом добавить нумерацию, вывод на экран и запись в файл можно делать в одном цикле, итерируясь по строкам файла. Проблема оригинального кода была в том что цикл по `v` не отрабатывал. Ну и на будущее - имена переменным лучше давать осмысленные в большом коде с однобуквенными именами будет сложно работать.

```
file_name = str(input('Введите имя файла: '))
original_file = open(f'D:\\Txtfiles\\{file_name}')
copied_file = open('D:\\Txtfiles\\3.txt', 'w+t')
line_number = 0
for line in original_file.readlines():
    line_number += 1
    print(line.replace('\n', '')) # вывод без пустых строк
    copied_file.write(str(line_number) + ')' + line)
copied_file.close()
original_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil

def main():
    file_name = input("Введите имя файла: ")
    Print_Text_in_File(file_name)
    Copy_File(file_name)


def Copy_File(file_name):
    # Read
    lines = []
    num = 1
    with open(str(file_name), "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            lines.append(f"{str(num)}) {line}")
            num = num + 1
    # Write
    with open("1)" + str(file_name), "w+") as file:
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line)
        

def Print_Text_in_File(file_name):
    with open(str(file_name)) as file:
        print(file.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Работает, я тестил